# Как реализовать проверку условия параллельно работе бота в telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

пишу телеграмм бота, который получает дату трансляции от администратора, далее ждет момента, когда останется 3 дня до трансляции и сообщает об этом админу. Проверка разницы дат должна выполняться постоянно, но при этом бот должен способен принимать сообщения и на них отвечать, как этого можно достичь?

```
import telebot
import datetime
from telebot import types

date = "2020-01-01 00:00:00.0"
offset = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=3))
link = ""
date_time_stream = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    ...
    
    ...

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def mes(message):
    ...

    ...

# часть, которая должна постоянно проверять разницу дат

date_now = datetime.datetime.now(offset)
different = date_time_stream.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) - date_now.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
print(different)
if different.days == 3 and different.hour == 0 and different.minute == 0 and different.seconds == 0:
    bot.send_message(admin_id, text="Осталось 3 дня до трансляции")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать асинхронную задачу и использовать `asyncio` для достижения этой цели:

```py
# ...
import asyncio

# Ваш код для настройки бота

date = "2023-09-30 12:00:00.0"  # Установите дату трансляции
date_time_stream = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
admin_id = 123456789  # Замените на ID вашего администратора

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    # Обработка команды /start
    ...

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def mes(message):
    # Обработка текстовых сообщений
    ...

async def check_stream_date():
    while True:
        date_now = datetime.datetime.now()
        difference = date_time_stream - date_now
        if difference.days == 3 and difference.seconds == 0:
            await bot.send_message(admin_id, text="Осталось 3 дня до трансляции")
        await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Проверка каждую минуту

# Запуск асинхронной задачи для проверки разницы дат
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(check_stream_date())

# Запуск бота
if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Данная асинхронная задача (функция `check_stream_date`) будет работать параллельно обычным, и каждую минуту проверять разницу дат.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне не помогло это решить проблему. Переписал отрывок кода, но все равно сам бот работает, а проверка даты не происходит